# .htaccess Redict URLs without File Extensions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

mit `.htaccess` looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|css|jpg|png|ico|txt|html)$ index.php [L]
```

It allow normal access to the URLs with the listed file extensions. All other requests are sent to the index.php.

**How can I simplify my .htaccess so it allows all file requests and redicts only requests without file extension to the index.php?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I assume that your .htaccess is located in your documentroot. Otherwise try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Both examples would send all traffic to index.php except those to physically existing files.

Comment: Your assumption was right and the first snipped works for me! Thanks.